# Javafx table view multiple selection sometimes skips one of the items

Tags: javafx, null, tableview

I have created a table view in javafx for my custom object. I have enabled multiple selection in the code by doing: 
`table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`

Randomly I observe that when I select all the items by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, one of the items is returned as **null** among all the selected items. Not sure why this happens. 
I use below line to fetch all items:

```
ObservableList<MyObj> selectedItems = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: maybe the `index -1` ?

Comment: i see the same issue, the index returned for the null object is -1 . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893979/javafx8-tableview-multiselection-returns-one-of-the-selected-items-as-null.  Were you able to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's a bug, already fixed for version 9 (and also 8u112, if I understand correctly): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144501

A workaround for now is to use `getSelectedIndices()`, then get the items corresponding to these instances from `table.getItems()`